# Get Most Recurring Value Within Grouped Results

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to select a user's preferred category based on occurrences within a database.

I tried the following example based on another question but the results were not as expected.

```
SELECT thread_id AS tid,
    (SELECT user_id FROM thread_posts 
        WHERE thread_id = tid 
        GROUP BY user_id
        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
        LIMIT 0,1) AS topUser
FROM thread_posts
GROUP BY thread_id
```

My table establishes a single user by two columns `User Section` and `User Sub Section`.

```
User Section | User Sub Section | Category
------------------------------------------
1            | A                | Foo
1            | A                | Bar
1            | A                | Foo
1            | B                | 123
2            | A                | Bar
2            | A                | Bar
2            | A                | Bar
2            | A                | Foo
3            | A                | 123
3            | A                | 123
3            | B                | Bar
4            | A                | Foo
```

Expected Results

```
User Section | User Sub Section | Category
------------------------------------------
1            | A                | Foo
1            | B                | 123
2            | A                | Bar
3            | A                | 123
3            | B                | Bar
4            | A                | Foo
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function comes in handy here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT section, sub_section, category,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY section, sub_section
                              ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY section, sub_section, category
)

SELECT section, sub_section, category
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY section, sub_section;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Many thanks. There's a lot happening in this, i'm going to spend some time analysing it and understanding the logic. It seems though that it requires MySQL version 8, I am running version 5.7. I tried modifying your query but can't get it to work with version 5.7 :(

Comment: I was advised to repost stating the mysql version, which I ave now done https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72865945/get-most-recurring-value-within-grouped-results-mysql-version-5-7

Comment: @Steve Thanks for doing this...it is a very ugly query on MySQL 5.7.  If you have a long term need for this sort of thing, then upgrade...besides 5.7 will not be supported forever anyway.