# Get Most Recurring Value Within Grouped Results MySQL version 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I would like to select a user's preferred category based on occurrences within a database.

I am using `MySQL` version `5.7`. I tried the following example based on another question but the results were not as expected.

```
SELECT thread_id AS tid,
    (SELECT user_id FROM thread_posts 
        WHERE thread_id = tid 
        GROUP BY user_id
        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
        LIMIT 0,1) AS topUser
FROM thread_posts
GROUP BY thread_id
```

My table establishes a single user by two columns `User Section` and `User Sub Section`.

```
User Section | User Sub Section | Category
------------------------------------------
1            | A                | Foo
1            | A                | Bar
1            | A                | Foo
1            | B                | 123
2            | A                | Bar
2            | A                | Bar
2            | A                | Bar
2            | A                | Foo
3            | A                | 123
3            | A                | 123
3            | B                | Bar
4            | A                | Foo
```

Expected Results

```
User Section | User Sub Section | Category
------------------------------------------
1            | A                | Foo
1            | B                | 123
2            | A                | Bar
3            | A                | 123
3            | B                | Bar
4            | A                | Foo
```

I'm using MySQL version 5.7. I was advised to delete my previous question and repost stating the MySQL version number, as a lot of functionality that exists in MySQL 8 doesn't exist in previous versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hairy problem to handle on MySQL 5.7.  Here is one approach:

```sql
SELECT s1.section, s1.sub_section, s1.category
FROM
(
    SELECT section, sub_section, category, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY section, sub_section, category
) s1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT section, sub_section, MAX(cnt) AS max_cnt
    FROM
    (
        SELECT section, sub_section, category, COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM yourTable
        GROUP BY section, sub_section, category
    ) t
    GROUP BY section, sub_section
) s2
    ON s2.section = s1.section AND
       s2.sub_section = s1.sub_section AND
       s1.cnt = s2.max_cnt
ORDER BY s1.section, s1.sub_section, s1.category;
```

Here is a running [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fa7bc1aa7fca6c3dc77fcf5c55c0dc15).

Comment: Thanks, as you say it does look a lot more involved than the version 8 example. I've ran a test and it works well. The only issue is that it pulls in the same user multiple times if they have the same `count` for a specific category. I'm not sure of there's a way of modifying it to pull in the latest rows that meet the same criteria?

Comment: ...in that case, you would need to provide a column(s) which lets us break the tie.

Comment: There is an auto incrementing id column that may fit that purpose? I'm not sure where in the code to add the condition though?